# Is this possible to recording video and uploading to remote server at the same time in Android?

Tags: android, android-video-player

I want to do video recording and  at the same time uploading that video to remote server in android application. Is this possible?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Actually No. The ratio between the size of a video and a network upload capacity in a given interval of time is to low to simultaneously upload/record video stream, unless the user has a very fast LTE cellular connection.

However, when the recording is done, you can upload the file to your server via a FTP protocol. It is recommended to give each recorded file an Universal Unique Identifier (UUID) to be able to make the difference between all the other recorded files.I made you a summary.

**Summary**

1. Generate a UUID with UUID.randomUUID().toString(); that will be used
   during the whole process to identify the recorded file.
2. Record the file with as name "sdcard/" + uuid + ".3gp"
3. When recording ends, upload the file to your server via a FTP
   upload.
4. Order your remote server to execute the PHP script that do whatever
   it needs to do with the recorded file, like database manipulation,
   etc. (if there is such a script, if you don't need to do this, just
   skip this step).
5. Order your remote server to delete the file, if needed to. (done via
           another PHP script)

Here is a sample for it [Android Uploading Camera Video to Server](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, if you allow for some delay. You would need to store the frames of your video and then start uploading them may be in an background thread (a classical producer consumer problem). To get the frames you can use the [ImageReader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ImageReader.html) class which can accept [CameraDevice](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraDevice.html) as a producer of image data from the new Camera2 API.

Then Implement [ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener.html) as a consumer class to get the latest image data from the ImageReader queue.

Answer (score -1):

```
    package pack.coderzheaven;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.<span class="IL_AD" id="IL_AD12">MediaStore</span>;
import android.util.Log;

public class UploadAudioDemo extends Activity {

    private static final int SELECT_AUDIO = 2;
    String selectedPath = "";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        openGalleryAudio();
    }

    public void openGalleryAudio(){

    Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("audio/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Audio "), SELECT_AUDIO);
   }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            if (requestCode == SELECT_AUDIO)
            {
                System.out.println("SELECT_AUDIO");
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedPath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                System.out.println("SELECT_AUDIO Path : " + selectedPath);
                doFileUpload();
            }

        }
    }

    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }

    private void doFileUpload(){
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        DataInputStream inStream = null;
        String lineEnd = "rn";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary =  "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;
        String responseFromServer = "";
        String urlString = "http://your_website.com/upload_audio_test/upload_audio.php";
        try
        {
         //------------------ CLIENT REQUEST
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(selectedPath) );
         // open a URL connection to the Servlet
         URL url = new URL(urlString);
         // Open a <span class="IL_AD" id="IL_AD10">HTTP connection</span> to the URL
         conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
         // <span class="IL_AD" id="IL_AD6">Allow</span> Inputs
         conn.setDoInput(true);
         // Allow Outputs
         conn.setDoOutput(true);
         // Don't use a cached copy.
         conn.setUseCaches(false);
         // Use a post method.
         conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
         conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
         conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);
         dos = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream() );
         dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
         dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadedfile";filename="" + selectedPath + """ + lineEnd);
         dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
         // create a buffer of maximum size
         bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
         bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
         buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
         // read file and write it into form...
         bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
         while (bytesRead > 0)
         {
          dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
          bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
          bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
          bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
         }
         // send multipart form data necesssary after <span class="IL_AD" id="IL_AD8">file data</span>...
         dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
         dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
         // close streams
         Log.e("Debug","File is written");
         fileInputStream.close();
         dos.flush();
         dos.close();
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException ex)
        {
             Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
             Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
        }
        //------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE
        try {
              inStream = new DataInputStream ( conn.getInputStream() );
              String str;

              while (( str = inStream.readLine()) != null)
              {
                   Log.e("Debug","Server Response "+str);
              }
              inStream.close();

        }
        catch (IOException ioex){
             Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
        }
      }
}
```